# PMD Configuration For Salesforce

Tags: apex, pmd

I am new PMD tool, i did below steps to configure PMD for salesforce and unable to proceed. Can anyone please help me here. Please tell me if i am missing something.

1. I have downloaded the PMD for Windows from https://pmd.github.io/
2. Configured the Environment Variable Path as D:\pmd-bin-6.46.0\bin
3. I have opned CMD and type PMD. it says below and i am unable to continue

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.2274]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\18963>PMD
The following option is required: --rulesets, -rulesets, -R
Run with --help for command line help.

C:\Users\18963>

Cheers,
Bheema.

Comment: Hi Bheema, you need an XML file with all the rules you want to apply, you can find a example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293585/7407067). you need to specify the file you want to analyze (`-d`) and the rules you want to enforce on the file (`-R`) , something like this: `pmd -d "c:\Users\workspace\NPE.cls" -R "C:\Users\workspace\Tools\pmd_apex_rules.xml" -f xml`

Comment: you may also find this link useful: [Apex PMD](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex.html)

Comment: Thanks, @McCubo. I was able to proceed to next step. Now i am run with given commands for files, i am not able to see the output file generated i get below.                   
 C:\Users\18963>pmd -d "D:\FPAN VS Code\FPAN_ModuleBox2\force-app\main\default\classes\FPAN_HPF_PrimaryFacilityUpdate.cls" -R "D:\pmd-bin-6.46.0\pmd_apex_rules.xml" -f xml

Comment: Jun 14, 2022 2:54:38 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleSetReferenceNode
WARNING: The RuleSet rulesets/java/basic.xml has been deprecated and will be removed in PMD 7.0.0

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report_2_0_0.xsd" version="6.46.0" timestamp="2022-06-14T14:54Jun 14, 2022 2:54:38 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD encourageToUseIncrementalAnalysis
WARNING: This analysis could be faster, please consider using Incremental Analysis: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.46.0/pmd_userdocs_incremental_analysis.html
:38.059">
</pmd>

Comment: if you need a file with all the results, you can add the `--report-file` parameter followed by  a path were the file will be written, try something like this: `--report-file "C:\Users\workspace\Tools\output.txt"`, you can also see all the parameters (and their description) supported by the pmd command by typing: `pmd --help`. hope this helps

Comment: @McCubo Thanks that Helped, appreciate it..!!